# tidesdk missing form variables

Tags: php, tidesdk

I have searched similar questions but none of the solutions have worked for me.

I have a simple form as shown below.

```
<form method="post" action="login.php" name="login-form" id="login-form">
                        <table style="margin: 0 auto; width: 250px;">
                            <tr>
                                <td style="padding-top: 20px;">
                                    <div class="input-group margin-bottom-sm"> 
                                        <span class="input-group-addon"> 
                                            <i class="fa fa-user fa-fw"></i>
                                         </span>
                                        <input name="username" class="form-control custom-input" type="text" placeholder="Username" id="focusedInput">
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td style="padding-top: 15px;">
                                    <div class="input-group"> 
                                        <span class="input-group-addon">
                                            <i class="fa fa-key fa-fw"></i>
                                         </span>
                                        <input name="password" class="form-control" type="password" placeholder="Password">
                                        <input id='loginSubmit' name='loginSubmit' type="hidden" value="<?php print md5(time()); ?>">
                                  </div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td style="padding-top: 15px;">
                                    <button name="login" id="login" type="submit" class="btn-inverse button-custom" data-section="2">
                                        Sign In
                                        <i class="fa fa-sign-in fa-fw"></i>
                                    </button>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </form>
```

This form is submitted to **login.php** file as shown below.

```
 <?php 

 print_r($_REQUEST);
 print_r($_GET);
 print_r($_POST);

?>
```

My problem is that when I submit the form I am not able to get the form variables on the login.php file. All three arrays contain nothing.

Am I doing anything wrong here?

My code works fine outside tideSDK. The launcher doesn't show any errors. Can any one please help me with this? or explain where I can see detailed error messages?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Assign your inputs to variables. I.e. `$username=$_POST['username']; echo $username;` etc.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Tried. But not working.

Comment: Then change your submit button to this `<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Sign In">` tested and working for me.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Doesn't work.

Comment: Ok I deleted my answer. Strange how it wouldn't work in your tideSDK. Oh well, just glad you found the answer, cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the problem hope this helps someone else.

Apparently tideSDK treats GET and POST in the same manner. So you don't have to specify the form method attribute on the forms and the form variables can be accessed using $_GET as shown in the code below.

```
<form action="login.php">
    <input type="text" name="username" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

These can be retrived in login.php as:

```
<?php
      print $_GET['username'];
?>
```

Comment: But what about long forms with more than 2048 characters? Then "post" should be used!

Comment: ... but it's not available -.-

Comment: @julmot Don't use tidesdk. Its still in beta stage and its has many limitations. Try this link http://www.sitepoint.com/3-ways-develop-cross-platform-desktop-apps-php/

Comment: Hi, I've just read the post but unfortunately I don't have an alternative for TideSDK after reading it. What are you using to handle post-requests inside the app?